# launchWebAuthFlow with Twitter OAuth 1.0a returns "Authorization page could not be loaded"

Tags: google-chrome-extension, twitter-oauth

I am trying to add a Sign in with Twitter option on my Chrome extension with this code:

```
// Send request to our backend, which calls
// https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token to get the OAuth token
const response = await postData({
 url: '/auth/twitter/reverse',
 headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
});

const authUrl = new URL('https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate');
authUrl.searchParams.set('oauth_token', response.data.oauth_token);
authUrl.searchParams.set('force_login', 'false');

chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow({ url: authUrl.href, interactive: true }, (responseUrl) => {
  // responseUrl is undefined
});
```

The OAuth dialog appears, and I can sign into Twitter successfully. When the window closes, it shows this error message in the console: `Unchecked runtime.lastError: Authorization page could not be loaded.`

My OAuth flow works fine on a website. I realize the Chrome Identity API is made for OAuth 2, so I'm not sure if there's a way to make Twitter OAuth 1.0a work with it.

How can I further debug and fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it! I was using a different callback URL than the `https://<app_id>.chromiumapp.org/` one.

Here's the updated code for making a request to my backend:

```
// Send request to our backend, which calls
// https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token to get the OAuth token
const response = await postData({
 url: '/auth/twitter/reverse',
 data: {
   callbackUrl: chrome.identity.getRedirectURL()
 },
 headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
});

...
```

My backend had the callback URL hardcoded, so I made it use the one passed in the request body.

Next, on the Twitter Developer Portal, I added my `https://<app_id>.chromiumapp.org/` URL to the **Callback URI / Redirect URL** section.

[image]

Remember, of course, to replace `app_id` with the name of your Chrome Extension app ID.